# Search and replace --.sub(replacement, string[, count=0])-does not work with special characters

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am learning Python and Regex and I do some simple exercises.
Here I have a string and I want to replace special characters with html code.  The code is the following:

```
str= '\nAxes.hist\tPlot a histogram.\nAxes.hist2d\tMake a 2D histogram plot.\nContours\nAxes.clabel\tLabel a contour plot.\nAxes.contour\tPlot contours.'

p = re.compile('(\\t)')
p.sub('<\span>', str)
p = re.compile('(\\n)')
p.sub('<p>', str)
```

This code leaves the special characters (`\n` and `\t`) unaltered.

I have tested the regex pattern on regex101.com and it works.  I can not understand why the code is not working.

Comment: Did you try without escaping carriage and tab? It's not escaped in your string. Also, do not use `str` as a variable name, ever.

Comment: At least, don't redefine `str` in *Python*, where it is the name of a standard type. It's fine to use `str` as a variable name in, say, C.

Comment: Use `r'raw strings'` for regex, otherwise backslashes will give you no end of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you’re executing the `sub` method and not capturing
the result. It doesn’t change the string in-place. It returns a *new*
string.

Thus (using `s` instead of `str` for reasons explained above):

```
p = re.compile('(\\t)')
s = p.sub('<\span>', s)
p = re.compile('(\\n)')
s = p.sub('<p>', s)
```

Note that `\n` and `\t` will work as well.

Comment: Thanks!  However your code replaces \t with <\\span> rather with <\span> for reasons I can not comprehend.

Comment: If you’re looking at it in interactive mode, then yes, you’ll see backslashes doubled, because it’s showing you the *representation*, in the same form as one would use in source code. But if you display it with `print(s)`, you’ll get it in a more readable (but more ambiguous) mode. Look up `str()` vs. `repr()`.