# Search and replace --.sub(replacement, string[, count=0])-does not replace special character \

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, special-characters

I have a string and I want to replace special characters with html code. The code is as follows:

```
s= '\nAxes.axvline\tAdd a vertical line across the axes.\nAxes.axvspan\tAdd a vertical span (rectangle) across the axes.\nSpectral\nAxes.acorr'

p = re.compile('(\\t)')
s= p.sub('<\span>', s)
p = re.compile('(\\n)')
s = p.sub('<p>', s)
```

This code replaces `\t` in the string with `<\\span>` rather than with `<\span>` as asked by the code.

I have tested the regex pattern on regex101.com and it works. I cannot understand why the code is not working.

My objective is to use the output as html code.  The '<\span>' string is not recognized as a Tag by HTML and thus it is useless.  I must find a way to replace the \t in the text with <\span> and not with <\span>.  Is this impossible in Python?  I have posted earlier a similar question but that question did not specifically addressed the problem that I raise here, neither was making clear my objective to use the corrected text as HTML code.  The answer that was received did not function properly, possibly because the person responding was negligent of these facts.

Comment: Shouldn't you specify only one backslash?

Comment: How has this moved on from [your earlier attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41793647/search-and-replace-subreplacement-string-count-0-does-not-work-with-spe)? You should still use `r'raw strings'`, and a backslash isn't actually valid syntax for closing an element.

Comment: Also note that `'<\\span>'` is just how Python represents the string `<\span>`, to make it clear that there's a literal backslash rather than an escape character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it *does* work. It's just that you printed the `repr` of it. Were you testing this in the python shell?

In the python shell:

```
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> print('\\')
\
>>> print(repr('\\'))
'\\'
>>>
```

The shell outputs the returned value (if it's not `None`) using the the `repr` function. To overcome
this, you can use the `print` function, which returns `None` (so is not outputted by the shell), and 
doesn't call the `repr` function.

Note that in this case, you don't need regex. You just do a simple `replace`:

```
s = s.replace('\n', '<p>').replace('\t', '<\span>')
```

And, for your regex, you should prefix your strings with `r`:

```
compiled_regex = re.compile(r'[a-z]+\s?') # for example
matchobj = compiled_regex.search('in this normal string')
othermatchobj = compiled_regex.search('in this other string')
```

Note that if you're not using your compile regex more than once, you can do this in one step

```
matchobj = re.search(r'[a-z]+\s?', '<- the pattern -> the string to search in')
```

Regex are super powerful though. Don't give up!